# create Excel sheet between existing sheet using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I build the code to meet my client requirement using org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet class

Now I got a new requirement  to create a new excel sheet in between two existing sheets. In the existing excel file there are already three sheets at the index numbers p,1,2. I want to create a sheet at index number 2 moving the sheet at index number 2 to 3.

I could able to find the sheets names in Excel file using the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) 
        {  
          System.out.println("Sheet name: " + wb.getSheetName(i));
        }
```

Also, I could able to find the sheet index numbres in Excel file using the code:

```
System.out.println("Sheet name: " + wb.getSheetIndex("Retail - All"));
```

The code I used to create a new sheet is: `Sheet failuresSheet= wb.createSheet("Failures");` This is creating a new sheet at end. Please let me know the correct code for my requirement.

Remember that I used the class `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet` to meet my requirement.

Please let me know how to create a sheet at Index no 2 moving the sheet at index no 2 to 3. Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at [this](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#setSheetOrder%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) javadoc, you could change the shhet order with that method.
So you need:

```
wb.setSheetOrder("Failures",1); //the index is 0 based
```

Comment: Thank you, my requirement is met. The code you have suggested is working fine.